# Android - popover controller same as ipad

Tags: android, popover

Here is a popover controller of the ipad.

[image]

**Any idea on how do we create the same kind of thing in Android? Actually i want to display html file or load webview with URL.**

Comment: Can you be more specific? The screenshot is from an ipad? Calling a webview for a menu could be bad if the user is not connected...

Comment: Webview doesn't necessarily mean remote html file, can also be local. Might be easier to create than native, depends on what design/layouts he wants to put in there.

Comment: see https://github.com/lupidan/PopoverView

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use this 3D QuickAction

[image: 3D QuickAction]
[image]

This is an open source project. You can get it here: http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/

Comment: ya i had downloaded the same in past, but i havent implemented it yet. Let me implement the quick action you have mentioned. Thanx for your support.

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this using a custom dialog (public class MenuDialog extends Dialog) that is semi-transparent (use alpha value in your bg color like #88000000). Set its content view to any XML layout you like, include a `WebView` if you want.

And in the constructor, you probably could put something like:

```
Window window = getWindow();
window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);

window.requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
window.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);

window.setBackgroundDrawable(  
    context.getResources().getDrawable(android.R.color.transparent) );
```