# Android: how to build a ballon

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I have a ballon like Google map?[image]

Comment: Perhaps this question is what you're after: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663912/android-popover-controller-same-as-ipad

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that is a [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html)

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this.](http://code.google.com/p/simple-quickactions/) It's called Quick Actions.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [GreenDroid](http://greendroid.cyrilmottier.com/). This library is great for UI. It contains a component like action bar which I think you can find useful.