# Android Spinner different View for Spinner not items

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

Is there anyway to set different layout for `Dropdown` Spinner View itself not its items ?!
I mean I know that we can set layout for Dropdown Spinner items by inflating custom layout using `getDropDownView` in Spinner `ArrayAdapter` , but it changed view of the rows not spinner dropdown view itself . I want to change it to something like this :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPevP.png

(sorry , I didn't have enough reputation to post image )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a button instead of `spinner` widget and use [3D QuickAction](https://github.com/lorensiuswlt). This will allow you to have iPad Popover kind of look n feel. Get help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663912/android-popover-controller-same-as-ipad) and [here](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/)